Unable to load one or more Anti-Cheat components on Splitgate
I'm trying to play Splitgate on Steam, but I keep getting a big error popup as soon as I try to launch the game. Something about the Anti-Cheat not working:

Unable to load one or more Anti-Cheat components.

This is most likely due to security software (Anti-Virus/Firewall)
deleting critical files or otherwise interfering with the loading
process.

Error message from Windows:
1275: This driver has been blocked from loading

Try the following to fix the issue:
1) Update your security software to the latest version.
2) Add an exclusion rule in your security software for:
C:\ProgramData\EQU8
3) Temporarily disable your security software to see if the
problem goes away.
4) Restart your system.

If the problem persists, please contact support and provide
the code: 0x4fb600400dd.

You can press Ctrl+C to copy this message.

I've tried the recommended fix in the popup, but it doesn't work.

That's a unique one, no search results for that error code :(

Out of curiosity, did you also try disabling Defender and SmartScreen? If not, it's worth a shot. After that, your next step would be to try allow loading unsigned drivers via advanced startup settings, but that's obviously not advisable in the long (or short) term.

@Hoppeduppeanut I have tried disabling my Anti-Virus (Defender), but this doesn't make a difference.

Splitgate uses an Anti Cheat called EQU8. This Anti Cheat loads a driver in your system to prevent cheating.
The error code you got is 1275 or 0x4FB, which corresponds to the Windows Error Code ERROR_DRIVER_BLOCKED. This usually happens when:

The driver file is corrupted (check the integrity of the game just to make sure)
The digital signature on the driver is not valid because the time of your computer is wrong (go to your Windows settings and set the time correctly)
The driver has been backlisted by Microsoft via the Microsoft vulnerable driver blocklist due to security vulnerabilities or bugs
Reputation based protection detected the Anti Cheat doing something suspicious and might have temporarily blacklisted the driver

What I would recommend is checking the integrity of the game to see if it fixes it, if not, a game reinstall would be a good idea.
